# Coupon Site - Store Slug Preference (Domain name or Store Name)

Tags: seo

What do you guys think of the slug for store name. Domain name of the store or the Full name of the store. All top sites have different models.

Domain Name

- `http://example.com/coupons/saksoff5th.com`
- `http://example.com/coupons/kohls.com`

Store Name

- `http://example.com/coupons/saksfifthavenueoff5th`
- `http://example.com/coupons/kohls`

Does one have a preference in terms of SEO or usability?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a preference for SEO and if there is, the benefit is marginal. I would personally choose to go with the .com or TLD version as users will most likely recognize brand websites and could lead to higher CTR. You do stand to run into a problem if brands have sub-brands or similar brands compete with a brand.

For example, people would search for "apple coupons" just as they would "iphone coupons" however iphones fall under apple.com site and not on their own site like iphone.com. Coupon sites have taken this into consideration and have the sub-brand (iphone) under the brand (apple) category like this:

> `example.com/coupons/iphone`
>   **Home > Electronics > Apple > iPhone**

Think about how you would handle these scenarios on the backend in your database to help decide what is best/easiest for your team.

Answer (score 1):

> Domain Name or Store Name

This would seem to lean towards being "primarily opinion based" I would think? Whilst I agree with the points raised in David's answer, personally, I would go with the "Store Name" in the URL, over the "Domain Name".

I would think people would be more familiar with the store name / brand name, rather than the store's specific domain name - although the two are often intrinsically linked. Particularly with stores that originate in the high street. Do users really know (or care) whether their favourite store is a `.com` or `.co.uk`? What about sites that work on a multitude of TLDs like eBay and Amazon, etc.?